# What is the maximum number of transactions for authorize.net sandbox account?

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I want to know that is there any limit for authorize.net sandbox account for test transactions?

I mean how many transactions I can do for my CIM tests in a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit. You can run as many as you need to.